# Using Typhoeus to POST an array to a URL

Tags: ruby, typhoeus

I'm using Typhoeus to post a hash to my API url.  It's actually an array containing a set of hashes.  Here's effectively what I'm doing:

```
companies = Array.new
company = { 'name' => 'Company 1' , 'company_url' => 'http://company.com' }
companies.push(company)
company2 = {'name' => 'Company 2' , 'company_url' => 'http://company2.com' }
companies.push(company2)

request = Typhoeus::Request.post("http://myapi.com/1.0/startups/create_batch",
                                 :username => 'user',
                                 :password => 'password',
                                 :auth_method => :basic,
                                 :params => {'companies' => companies} )
print "Create_batch response "+request.body
```

Once I run the script I get the output which states "Create_batch response Disallowed Key Characters.".  I'm not sure what it's referencing at this point.  I've looked over the text output of what print companies shows up but I don't see any strange code.

Anybody have any insights on what I should do?

Comment: What's the variable startups referencing? Did you mean companies?

Comment: Also, have you tried to post the URLs without the http:// part? That would be the only "weird" thing I see.

Comment: The code example doesn't look correct. As @SrdjanPejic said, what is `startups`? How does the code access the values in `companies`? Also, you probably need to send JSON or do some sort of serialization on the `companies` array-of-hashes, to send it across the wire. Typhoeus won't do that for you because it has no knowledge of the type of data the far end expects. It's just the pipe really.

Comment: I've fixed the code ... Also by using JSON I was able to accomplish what I wanted to do.  I figured Typhoeus would do this for me but apparently it doesn't as the Tin Man states above